Where exactly to connect power cables on camera PCB board - not working
I have a camera PCB board where I need to connect power cables, but it's not functioning. I need help identifying the exact connection points and securing method.
It has to be somewhere on the bottom left part of the PCB.

Technical details:

Small camera PCB board
Red (positive) and black (negative) power cables


how is it powered now?

"It has to be somewhere on the bottom left part of the PCB." Why? What are the red and black soldered connections on the bottom right? How was it connected to the power source before dismantling? How do you know what voltage it requires? You haven't supplied details on make and model.
